# Interpretation of the output of graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz, decision-tree

I have trained the DecisionTreeClassifier for predicting the binary target. Then I visualized the tree as follows:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=20,max_depth=5,criterion="entropy",random_state=99)
dt.fit(df[important_features], target)

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from sklearn.tree import _tree
import graphviz

export_graphviz(dt, out_file="tree.dot",
                feature_names=important_features)
with open("tree.dot") as f:
    dot_graph = f.read()
graphviz.Source(dot_graph)
```

In the tree I see that the last level has information like, e.g.:

```
entropy = 0.9908
samples = 67465
value = [37538, 29927]
```

However I cannot find the `target` that should be the binary variable. I expected to see it in the last lowest level of the tree and thus analyzet the rules/paths to `0` and `1`. What an I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. However, you did set `max_depth = 5`, how is it supposed to show the target if the tree hasn't split completely?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy: I misunderstood this concept. How then should I set `max_depth` to see the target?

Comment: I've only used `graphiz` once before, you can leave that argument blank and the tree will expand fully. You should be able to then see the bottom most layer. However, when I used it my tree was so massive I couldn't see anything in the pdf.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy: In this case it's probably necessary to make pruning, but I don't have any idea how to do it? I know how to prune trees in R, but no idea about python. Do you know the answer?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately Python does not have a pruning option yet, sorry =(. You could technically write your own code for it, but my math is not on that level to pull off something like that.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy: well, I think you answered my initial question. So, if you publish the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I would leave this open in case anyone might have a solution or a more efficient way of seeing the tree. Thanks anyways!